How do I reserve virtual memory, only (de)allocating physical memory on demand
I would like a large contiguous buffer, possibly larger than available RAM ('contiguous' in userspace virtual memory, not physical memory). As only parts of the buffer will be used, I would like to allocate and deallocate physical the backing memory on demand, only keeping what is in use instead of loading the whole buffer. This led me to the following idea:
Management of physical memory addresses is abstracted away from the user. (In userspace, a section of contiguous virtual memory may be actually be fragmented in physical memory.) It seems that this principle could be used to implement several optimizations.

Multiple buffers from malloc could be 'merged' or 'split' from the view of userspace, by reassigning the virtual memory address to be contiguous while leaving the physical memory untouched. This would be a very cheap operation regardless of the size of the buffers.

By extension, fread could return contiguous buffers, without costly operations of copying the data into a buffer that the caller had to previously allocate (and also reducing RAM usage by allowing the caller and cache to share data.) fread would load the file by chunks on demand, assigning them a virtual memory address such that they form a contiguous buffer in virtual memory.


If this has not been done, I am sure that there are valid reasons; e.g. page-alignment, or protection of the data, but I would like to write a basic proof-of-concept to examine the possibilities.
malloc will allocate memory, but I cannot ensure that the addresses returned by multiple calls to malloc are contiguous in terms of virtual memory.
I can reserve virtual memory, only allocating it at access time using mmap with the MAP_NORESERVE flag, but as munmap can only delete whole mappings, I see no way to delete the physical memory corresponding with a specific portion of the virtual memory map.
Edit: The above is possible using madvise with MADV_DONTNEED / MADV_FREE on the pages no longer needed.
Can I allocate and deallocate chunks of physical memory, and assign them to parts of a contiguous virtual address space, or am I misunderstanding the virtual/physical memory relationship?

Does the madvise system call help with your use case?

"am I misunderstanding the virtual/physical memory relationship?" - Seems like you are (or you have poorly/incompletely described the situation). In userspace use malloc(), and in kernel mode use kmalloc(). Both will allocate a block of contiguous virtual memory that is backed by physical memory automatically as needed.

To avoid the potential for a XY problem can you describe the problem you are trying to solve. It isn't clear why a large contiguous virtual address space, of which only parts are backed by physical memory, is needed.

@sawdust Since I am trying to design a framework that can use large buffers (up to many GB and beyond) I don't want to waste RAM and CPU to malloc' the whole buffer, since I won't use it all, and definitely not all at once. I can manage by using malloc` to allocate it in chunks, but then I cannot operate over it as a contiguous space which would be very handy.  I am trying to understand if an OS can map distinct and separate physical memory allocations to a contiguous section of virtual memory in userspace.

@ChesterGillon Thank you, I have updated the question.

@ChesterGillon madvise with MADV_DONTNEED looks interesting, thank you.

"malloc will allocate physical memory" - Your expanded post simply reveals more of your misunderstanding. One more time: malloc() allocates virtual memory. Linux may not even backup that virtual memory with physical memory because of overcommit. You have not provided a sensible reason why malloc() cannot do what you want, e.g. a very large buffer that is sparsely used. One purpose of the OS is to abstract the hardware, such as physical memory. Your user program should have minimal awareness of physical vs virtual memory.

Study What a C programmer should know about memory

@sawdust  Thanks for the links. Those article are quite informative. I am not sure I completely understand all the concepts, but I have them bookmarked for the moment I forget something. :)
